# SignalR[Start must be called before data can be sent in windows service]

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am new in SignalR

In my application I have a Window service which used for sending signalr message and it is working fine in one mvc4 application.
Now I have to use the SignalR service in different project But that same service showing bellow error in the application.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us some relevant code?

Comment: Window service having SignalR version 1.0 and My new app is MVC5 and having signal version 2.0
Is there any issue? If yes then help me to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is fixed by just updating Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version to 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting indicates that you have not started your SignalR connection before attempting to send data over the connection.

You should be calling (Hub)Connection.Start() and waiting for the Task returned from that to complete successfully before attempting to send a message.

It should not matter that you are using SignalR 1.0 on the client and 2.0 on the server.